# How to achieve new page animation in Flutter that's similar to native iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-animation

Any idea if there's already a lib for achieving something similar to the native new page popup animation similar to iOS?

In this example image, you can see the new page when you click on New Reminder (you can basically find it in almost every native app):

[image]